# I need help making a discord bot direct message someone on typing a command

Tags: node.js, discord, dm, discord.js

I am currently trying to create a discord bot and am stumped on a command i am trying to make it do. The command is supposed to be a secret DM message sent by the bot. I was wondering if there was anyway to do this? the command is supposed to look like this:

> /dm @PLAYER#000 [message_goes_here]

Pleas help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this step by step:

If the @Player#0000 is a mention, you can get Player#0000's [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) Object using `msg.mentions[0].` Now on to sending that User a message:

Firstly you'll need to separate the message from the command:
Using [`msg.toString()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=toString) you'll be able to grab the message with the mention being turned into <@ID>, which will also account for spaces in usernames. Now split the message using `msg.toString().split(' ')`, `shift()` it twice, `join(' ')` it and you'll have the message.

Using [`User.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send) you will be able to message that user.

Here's how the final result will look:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('/dm ') && message.mentions.users.size) {
        var v=message.toString().split(' ').shift().shift().join(' ') // Takes the DM content from the message
        var member=message.mentions.users[0] // The mentioned user
        member.send(v) // send that user a DM
    }
})
```

Note that this example doesn't really cover errors (in case the message doesn't send, etc.)

Comment: When i try to run this code I get the error `message.startsWith is not a function on line 2`. Why is that?

Comment: my bad, `message.content.startsWith()`, message is not a String.

Comment: So then what should I replace `message.content.startsWith()` with?

Comment: What should I replace `message.content.startsWith()` with then?

Comment: NVM. Now its giving me the error: `message.toString(...).split(...).shift(...).shift is not a function`. What does that mean? Do I just change it to `message.content.toString(...).split(...).shift(...).shift`? @LW001

Comment: Can anybody else help me? Please?